# jQuery .ajax() method with special characters in data not working on IE 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, special-characters

I'm having an issue using jQuery's `.ajax` method when I send special characters to the data parameter, **but only on Internet Explorer 7**. It works on IE 8, 9, Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the peace of code:

```
jqxhr = $.ajax({url: "/aj_search/", async: true, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
  data: decodeURIComponent($('#crit_form').serialize(true)),
  success: function(json){ // process code}
});
```

Here is the data I am sending (when I print the decodeURIComponent result):

boite=Boîte+Manuelle&csrfmiddlewaretoken=ENFuL4ioBQ4nfkUESmkkAzNtHB7rhTKV&prix_min=0&prix_max=15&km=&annee_min=1989&annee_max=2012&dpt=&modeles=&page=1&p_page=10&sort_crit=weight&sort_dir=1&comps=&is_comp=0&ex_ma=&ex_mo=

The problem lies in **Boîte+Manuelle**. When I print what I get in my django view (data received on the server), I get:

```
Bo�te Manuelle
```

Any idea here? Why is this not working only on IE7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like IE7 is sending text in the wrong encoding...

Comment: how can I check that? By default the .ajax method in jquery sends UTF8 encoding...

Comment: Yes and IE7 seems to be sending Latin-1... Hence the diamond-with-question-mark. Maybe do an hex dump.

Comment: How to do an hex dump? I don't know that.

Comment: Print the data you receive in hexadecimal, instead of printing the string itself.

Comment: @EagleOne. why are you using `decodeURIComponent` anyways? What do you get if you just drop it?

Comment: @Alexander: I added that for encoding problems. It turns out I have been doing a lot since then and you are right. If I remove it works great in any situation... 
Please Alexander, add your response so that I can validated it.

Comment: @dda: thanks for your help. I didn't even had time to try to display hex. Thanks anyway

Comment: @EagleOne, ok, i posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `decodeURIComponent` anyways, try removing it.

Comment: you were right, I added it for some encoding problems a long time ago. I guess I don't need it anymore and that was the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try encodeURIcomponent instead

Comment: well...  the data option is what is getting sent to the server, not the response from the server.  Past experiences tell me that the data needs to be "encoded" when passing it to the server, and not "decoded"

Answer (score 0):

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ro.htm

this will help you for sure. Use the code given instead of the special character ok.